# Click Button With No ID Selenium Java

Tags: selenium

Apologies for this;

Event Triggers

Photos

Push Notifications

How can I Click on Event triggers for example using Selenium Java?

I've tried this code:

By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Event triggers')]");
        By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]");

I tried this as well:

WebElement Box= driver.findElement(By.tagName("Event triggers"));
Box.submit();

Neither of these worked...

Thank you

Comment: Add your code and the html

Comment: Apologies for this;

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a onclick="windowOpen(&quot;./controller.html&quot;);" href="javascript:void(0);">Event Triggers</a></li>
<li><a onclick="windowOpen(&quot;./ti_tile_photos.html&quot;);" href="javascript:void(0);">Photos</a></li>
<li><a onclick="windowOpen(&quot;./ti_notify_controller.html&quot;);" href="javascript:void(0);">Push Notifications</a></li></ul>

How can I Click on Event triggers for example using Selenium Java?

I've tried this code:

Comment: Future reference. There is an "edit" link under your question. Please add additional code using that instead of the comments. The formatting will also be better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to using this:

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Event triggers')]");
```

instead of

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Event triggers')]");
```

Comment: Maybe you have iframe at your page? So you should switch into it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the page source mentioned in the comment I think Event Triggers is not a button but an  tag which essentially makes it a link.
As you know the text of the link you are trying to click you can always use:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Event Triggers"));
```

to get Event Triggers web element.

Using xpath should be avoided due to slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if button doesnt have any id , you can try to write dynamic xpath by using "class name" and "type" (there are plenty of examples , you can learn easily how to create your xpath) , or easiest way, use firebug to locate element that you want to click and copy exact Xpath via firebug. And then click.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Event triggers')]").click();
```

You were missing that click action.